# How to config .htaccess file to view .html files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /wp-content/themes/public/$1 [L]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

My website is running by Wordpress and I have the public folder that contains some html files is used to demo the design. I want:

- If user access my website by URL: http://mydomain/* , it will display the web page by Wordpress
- If user access some demo file such as: http://mydomain/public/demo.html, it will display the demo.html file inside the public folder

So I made .htaccess like above for that purpose. It works in my localhost (I'm using XAMPP) but doesn't work on my server

My server is running Apache 2.4 by CentOS

I need any help, please...

Comment: Although your first rule internally rewrites all requests for the `/public/` subdirectory to `/wp-content/themes/public/` - so you aren't actually serving anything from the public folder as you state? "doesn't work on my server" - what happens exactly?

Comment: @MrWhite "doesn't work on my server" - what happens exactly?
It raise error 500 when I access http://mydomain/public/

Comment: You need to check the server's error log for the details of the "500 error". You may have a rewrite loop - but that's not obvious from what you've posted. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories along the filesystem path?